Is there any function for enable notification in react-native-ble-plx library?
I am using git hub documentation of react-native-ble-plx library(link - https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Characteristic-Notifying),
In which i have implemented the function for Character Notifying but i am getting remove() as in return,
I want my enable notification should return true or false value
const notificationListener = (error: Error | null, characteristic: Characteristic | null) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error in monitoring characteristic:", error);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Characteristic value:", characteristic?.value);
  };

  const enableNotification: any = async (
    bleManager: BleManager,
    deviceIdentifier: string,
    serviceUUID: string,
    characteristicUUID: string,
  ) => {
    try {

      const subscription = bleManager.monitorCharacteristicForDevice(
        deviceIdentifier,
        serviceUUID,
        characteristicUUID,
        notificationListener
      );
      console.log("Monitoring characteristic", subscription)
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Failed to enable notifications:", error);
    }
  };


Could you add a log to your question that shows that you receive "remove()"?
